# Transforming position to torque

Tags: robotic-arm, torque

first question in this forum :D

so i started creating a 2 link robotic arm in SIMULINK and made a function that builds its trajectory (cubic spline) and used it as an input for my joint. 
so my input was position and output was the torque etc.

Now i would like my input to be torque,how do i go about it?
should i create a transfer function out of the dynamic equation OR can i use the trajectory in someway OR is there a simple way?
If you have an answer i would appreciate if you can send a detailed explanation on  how you can do that in SIMULINK
[image]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Susanoo. As it stands, it's not quite clear what you're asking. If you want to supply a joint torque to the `Joint1` block, then you need to double click the joint, go to "Z Revolute Primitive" --> "Actuation" --> "Torque" and set it to "Provided by input," then set "Motion" to "Automatically computed." If you're asking *how* to generate a torque reference that you could pass to the torque input port for the joint, then the answer is however you want; open loop, PID, etc.

Comment: If you have a more specific question, then please *edit your question* to reflect those details - what you wanted to have happen, what you tried, what you saw, and what you expected to see.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)
I knew how to change the joint input, the question is how can i use my trajectory function or dynamic functions of the structure to create a torque input instead of position. i want to use torque control.

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve, test a torque controller you can just feed the joint with a smooth torque command, follow a velocity or position profile for the joint then you need to pass through the dynamics of your assembly and use inverse dynamics and classic control theory.

Answer (score 1):

1. As it is, I think your problem is under-specified.  You will need to specify $x$, $y$, $v_x$ and $v_y$, where $(x,y)$ is the tooltip position and $v_x$ and $v_y$ are the velocities in the two directions of the tooltip.
2. You will need the mass of each arm, say $m_1$ and $m_2$ as well as the mass of the actuator at the joint (let's call it $m_a$).
3. You will need the lengths of each link, $l_1$ and $l_2$.
4. Once you have all this, you can set up the torque equation for the arm and solve it using Lagrangians.  You can find some guidance on how to do this [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358412336_CASE_STUDIES_IN_DUAL-LINK_ROBOT_ARM_DYNAMICS).

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but maybe its a start.  It's also been 4 years since you posted the question, but since no one ever answered I thought I would take a shot.